# JS Switch HTML content based on specific text included in h1 tag

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm quite new to javascript and have been searching for a solution with no joy.

I want to switch the content of a certain p tag depending on if the H1 tag contains certain text. I aim to put this js in the  of every page ready for when it's needed.

I have figured out that 'if' and 'else if' should be a suitable way of doing it, but I would be open to other ideas. I have tried writing a 'switch' statement but I couldn't figure out how to get it working.

So far the closest I have found is..

```
<h1>This is about Red</h1>
<p id="colour"></p>

<script>
if('h1:contains("Red")'){
document.getElementById("colour").innerHTML = "Red description";
} else if ('h1:contains("Orange")'){
document.getElementById("colour").innerHTML = "Orange description";
} else if ('h1:contains("Green")'){
document.getElementById("colour").innerHTML = "Green description";
} else if ('h1:contains("Blue")'){
document.getElementById("colour").innerHTML = "Blue description";
}

</script>
```

...but the content of the p tag won't change when the H1 tag contains the other text, only the 'Red' text seems to work. Please could someone let me know where I am going wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: `'h1:contains("Red")'` does not mean anything in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is already an accepted answer, I'm adding this in to show a different approach that I believe to be a bit easier to expand upon for future use.

### Finding A Keyword

Similar to the accepted answer, using `.includes()` is how we will determine which color/keyword is located in the text, but I also like to use things like `.toLowerCase()` when doing string comparisons because case sensitivity can cause things like `.includes()` to return false if both words are not capitalized the same way.

### Using Objects

`if/else` and `switch()` statements can be useful, but I often tend to use objects or arrays of objects for situations that involve several different options. Objects also make it a bit easier to add to later on and customize.

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1"),
      description = document.querySelector("#colour"),
      colors = [
        { color: "red", description: "Red description" },
        { color: "orange", description: "Orange description" },
        { color: "green", description: "Green description" },
        { color: "blue", description: "Blue description" }
      ]
  
description.innerText = colors.filter(f => h1.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(f.color))[0]?.description
```

```html
<h1>This is about Red</h1>
<p id="colour"></p>
```

Essentially, this uses `.filter()` on the array of objects to find any object whose `color` property is found inside of the text of the `h1` element.

### Expanding/Updating

I don't know what the planned use-case for this is but I assume that you eventually won't literally want "***Red description***" if it finds the word "**Red**" anywhere in the text. Rather, you will probably have some other wording or sentences, which can easily be set in this object. And adding additional colors is as easy as copying another color/line and changing the text.

Comment: Ah brilliant, yes this works really well and you're correct, it allows me to write anything I like for the description appearing in the p tag. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer to your comment:**

If you want have some advanced if statements, you could use the if statements similar to your first approach:

```js
const elH1Content = document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML;
const elColour = document.getElementById("colour");

if (elH1Content) {
  if (elH1Content.includes("Red")) {
    elColour.innerHTML = "First one (red)";
  } else if (elH1Content.includes("Orange")) {
    elColour.innerHTML = "Second one (orange)";
  } else if (elH1Content.includes("Green")) {
    elColour.innerHTML = "Third one (green)";
  } else if (elH1Content.includes("Blue")) {
    elColour.innerHTML = "Forth one (blue)";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">This is about Blue</h1>
<p id="colour"></p>
```

I haven't seen `'h1:contains("Red")'` in an if statement in JavaScript before. Are you sure that is correct?

You could get the innerHTML of the H1 and then check if that string `.includes` the colour string.

Note that I gave the H1 element an id="h1" to access that element directly. Otherwise you would need to loop through all H1 elements on the page.

Comment: This works really well thank you, unfortunately I've found this doesn't quite work for my needs, as I need the output text in the #colour p tag to say a bit more than just 'Red', 'Blue' etc. Although these are still the strings I want to check for in the H1 tag. Is there a way of modifying this so that I can specify more for the innerHTML content?

Comment: I updated my answer. With those if statements you are a bit more flexible. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is another great solution, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Please use a selector for h1 element and then use its content for checking. This code will work.

```
const h1El = document.getElementById("sel")

if(h1El.textContent.includes('Red')){
document.getElementById("colour").innerHTML = "Red description";
} else if (h1El.textContent.includes('Orange')){
document.getElementById("colour").innerHTML = "Orange description";
} else if (h1El.textContent.includes('Green')){
document.getElementById("colour").innerHTML = "Green description";
} else if (h1El.textContent.includes('Blue')){
document.getElementById("colour").innerHTML = "Blue description";
}
```

Comment: How exactly does `if ('h1:contains("Red")')` work in JavaScript?

Comment: @Pointy It will not. We will have to use a selector.