# JS Change HTML img src based on specific text found in h1 tag

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement, switch-statement, include

I've posted a similar question regarding switching HTML text snippets (see [JS Switch HTML content based on specific text included in h1 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74864601/js-switch-html-content-based-on-specific-text-included-in-h1-tag/74864769?noredirect=1#comment132120220_74864769)), for which the replies were hugely helpful. From these replies, I used the following code to change the HTML text snippet:

```
<h1>This is about Red Apples</h1>
<span id="colour"></span>
```

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){ 
  const h1 = document.querySelector("h1"),
      description = document.querySelector("#colour"),
      colours = [
        { colour: "red", description: "red description" },
        { colour: "blue", description: "blue description" }
      ]
  
description.innerText = colours.filter(f => h1.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(f.colour))[0]?.description
  },false);
```

I now wish to modify the code to change the img src depending on some text (a different string of text from that required in my previous post) included in the h1 tag.

After lots of trial and error I can't figure out how to modify this code to change the image src on the same page. The closest I've got so far, but using the "if/else" method, is:

```
<h1>This is about Red Apples</h1>
<img id="fruitimage" src="default-image.jpg"/>
```

```
var map = {
    'red apples': 'redapples-image.jpg',
    'blue blueberries': 'blueberries-image.jpg',
    'yellow bananas': 'yellowbananas-image.jpg'
};

function influenceImage(source, map) {
    if (!source || !map) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var text = source.textContent || source.innerText;
        for (var word in map) {
            if (map.hasOwnProperty(word) && text.indexOf(word) !== -1) {
                return map[word];
            }
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById('fruitimage').imageNode.src = influenceImage(document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0], map);
```

However, I still cannot get this to work. I'm really hoping someone can help! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such thing as an `imageNode` property. Just remove `.imageNode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I see you have 2 errors in your code.

1 - remove `.imageNode`.

2 - you need to convert text to lower-case as the object key you are trying to get is in lower-case, use `.toLowerCase()`

```
var map = {
  "red apples": "redapples-image.jpg",
  "blue blueberries": "blueberries-image.jpg",
  "yellow bananas": "yellowbananas-image.jpg",
};

function influenceImage(source, map) {
  if (!source || !map) {
    return false;
  } else {
    let text = source.textContent.toLowerCase() || source.innerText.toLowerCase();3
    for (var word in map) {
      if (map.hasOwnProperty(word) && text.indexOf(word) !== -1) {
        return map[word];
      }
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("fruitimage").src = influenceImage( document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0], map);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for what you are trying to achieve

```js
var map = {
    'red apples': 'redapples-image.jpg',
    'blue blueberries': 'blueberries-image.jpg',
    'yellow bananas': 'yellowbananas-image.jpg'
};

function retImage(source) {
    var imageSource = "default-image.jpg";
    var text = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerText;
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(map)) {

        if (text.toLowerCase().includes(key)) {

            imageSource = val;
        }
    }
    let el = document.createElement("img");
    el.setAttribute("src", imageSource);
    el.setAttribute("alt", imageSource);
    document.getElementById("fruitimage").appendChild(el);
};

retImage() // function to return image
```

```html
<h1>This is about Red Apples</h1>
<div id="fruitimage"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your example misses a few bits here and there.

1. You still need some sort of an event listener to check if the DOM is fully loaded before you try and get any handle of your elements with `document.getElementById` in your case. (or place the JS script UNDER the dom, literally)
2. `influenceImage` name is pretty vague and is not doing what the name implies.

```js
// Utility function.
function getImageSrcByDescription(description) {
  const normalizedDescription = description.toLowerCase().trim()

  // Iterate over the array one item at a time.
  const image = IMAGE_TAGS_PAIRS.find((obj) => {

    // We split the tags by empty space delimiter.
    const tags = obj.tags.split(' ');

    // ... and make sure the provided description will contain all of the tags.
    const isMatchingAllTags = tags.every(tag => normalizedDescription.includes(tag))

    return isMatchingAllTags ? obj : undefined
  })
  
  // If image is found, return the `src` property of the object, if not, fallback.
  return image ? image.src : TAG_NOT_FOUND_IMG
}

// Act on page load.
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // Get handles for both description & image elements.
  const fruitDescriptionElem = document.querySelector('#fruit-description');
  const fruitImageElem = document.querySelector("#fruit-image");

  const description = fruitDescriptionElem.innerText
  const imageSrc = getImageSrcByDescription(description)

  if (imageSrc) {
    fruitImageElem.alt = 'New Image'
    fruitImageElem.src = imageSrc
  }
})
```

Here's a fiddle for you to play around.
https://jsfiddle.net/xjL79zef/1/